# Powerpoint effect for permanent style change?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have some object in a Powerpoint slide; let's say it's a textbox. The object is always visible - I never want it to "enter" or "exit"; but I do want, on mouse click, to change some feature of it; say, its text font size, or its fill color.

I know I can do this for a *limited* amount of time, using an emphasis effect. But I want to do this for an *unlimited* amount of time, and also not have anything else wait on this change to be "over".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I achieve this effect using one of two workarounds:

Option 1:

1. Duplicate the slide
2. Modify the element of interest on the second slide

Option 2:

1. Make a copy of the object
2. Modify the second object,
3. Add a "disappear" effect for the first object
4. Add an "appear" effect for the second object
5. Move the second object right on top of the first one

But I don't much care for either of these :-(